# Determining the trace of the k-th power of the adjacent matrix to a direct graph from observation and reasoning.

Tags: graph-theory

Take the digraph below,

[image]

It has two closed walks with vertices $(a,b,c)$ and $(e,d,f)$.

I have a proof in my notes of a theorem that concludes: The number of closed walks of length k in a digraph D is $tr(A^k)$.

I've been posed the question if 3 divides $k$ what is $tr(A^k)$ and if 3 doesn't divide $k$ what is $tr(A^k)$.

I want to conclude that for $k$ s.t. 3 divides $k$ $ \implies tr(A^k) = 2$ since there are two closed walks in the graph of length 3. And that for $k$ s.t. 3 doesn't divide $k$ $\implies tr(A^k) = 0$ since there are no other closed paths. I'm sceptical of my solution as I don't calculate $tr(A^k)$ - all I really do is reason using the fact that there are two closed path of length 3 and then use the result of the theorem I stated. Can I have some feed back on my solution or could someone tell me if I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the point of the question is to test your knowledge of the theorem, so your method is right. However, there are not just two closed walks (cycles). A better interpretation of the $(i,j)$th entry in the $k$th power of the adjacency matrix is the number of paths of length $k$ starting at vertex $i$ that end at vertex $j$. So even though there are two distinct cycles, you must count them each three times, since you can choose any vertex as the starting (and thus also ending) point. Therefore, $\text{tr}(A^k) = 6$, not $2$.

**EDIT:** Since we can traverse the three-cycles (e.g. $abc$) as many times as we want from any of its vertices, it follows that if $3$ divides $k$, then $(A^k)_{i,i} = 1$ for the vertices $i$ in the graph's two disjoint cycles, where $(A^k)_{i,i}$ is the $i$th diagonal element in the matrix $A^k$. Indeed, we have
$$\text{tr}(A^k) = \sum_{i = 1}^{|V|} (A^k)_{i,i} = 6$$

Similarly, since the graph's only cycles are two disjoint $3$-cycles, it follows that there are no cycles of length $k$ if $3$ does not divide $k$. This would of course imply that in this case $\text{tr}(A^k) = 0$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh shoot, you're right. As you could start at any node in the two sets I stated. Thanks! Just to clarify, am I still correct in saying that $tr(A^k) = 0$ for length $k$ s.t. 3 does not divide $k$. And is $tr(A^k)$ always 6 for any length $k$ s.t. 3 divides $k$ or did I get that wrong too.

Comment: See my edits. You are right.

Comment: This cleared up all my questions. Thank you very much for take the time to add that edit!